# Chaining 2 asynchronous calls (promise API) to run serially

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

This is similar to a question I posted [today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307652/promise-api-combining-results-of-2-asynchronous-call), but needs the request chained serially. I have two asynchronous requests, where the second request needs the result of first to send the query.

```
var Db.get = function(key){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

     //send async req
    var req = ....
    req.success = function(d){
        deferred.resolve(d)
    };
    req.failure = function(d){
        deferred.reject(d)
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

var someFn = function(id){
    Db.get(id, "abc")
        .then(function (d) {
            console.log("At 1")
            Db.get(d.id, "def")
                .then(function (d) {
                    console.log("At 2")
                    return d
                }, function (e) {
                    //error
                });
        }, function (e) {
            //error
        });

    console.log("At 3")
};
```

I should be thinking it wrongly, as I expect `console.log("At 3")` never to be printed in success scenario as I return after `console.log("At 2")`. But when I run, in the console I see these order

```
console.log("At 1")
console.log("At 3")
console.log("At 2")
```

I was thinking `then` would block till it get response from the promise (returned by get() ). so, everything in someFn execute serially. Is this assumption wrong? What is the best way to chain two asynchronous operation, which uses promises, to run serially.

Thanks.

### EDIT:

I tried what Ketan suggested [Chaining Ajax calls in AngularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284403/chaining-ajax-calls-in-angularjs) .

```
var someFn = function(id){
            Db.get(id, "abc")
                .then(function (d) {
                    console.log("At 1")
                    return Db.get(d.id, "def")
                }).then(function (d) {
                    console.log("At 2")
                    return d
                }, function (e) {
                    //error
                    return null;
                }).then(function (d) {
                    return d;
        });

        console.log("At 3")
    };
```

Still, if I make a call like

```
var res = someFn(1)
console.log(res) /// undefined
```

chrome terminal shows `At 2` after `undefined`. I am not sure why the result retuned by `someFn` not assigned to `res`.

Comment: See this question that Pawel answered yesterday.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284403/chaining-ajax-calls-in-angularjs

Comment: thanks Ketan. Will try it out.

Comment: Because `someFn` didn't return anything. You need to use `someFn().then()` and access the value from within the function passed to `then`. Check out this video where I discuss promises: https://plus.google.com/events/cljavmi7kpup1fso43k3fkpk2eg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was thinking then would block till it get response from the promise

No. Promises in JS are no transparent, blocking futures, but just a pattern to chain callbacks. The promise is returned before the callback is executed - and `At 3` is logged after `.then` returns, but before the callback executed. And if you `return` in the callback, it doesn't really matter to the outer `someFn`.

You rather would use something like

```
var someFn = function(id){
    return Db.get(id, "abc")
      .then(function (d) {
        console.log("At 1")
        return Db.get(d.id, "def");
      })
      .then(function (d) {
        console.log("At 2")
        return d
      }, function (e) {
        //error
      });
}
someFn().then(function(d) {
    console.log("At 3")
});
```

Comment: on the same vein, what if someFn is,say, 5th in the chain. So, promise somewhere in the chain force all the function call up in the chain to work with promise. Analogous to throwing exception down the chain. In short, if someFn is called by another function (someFn2), would the caller of the someFn2 also need to use .then() to call someFn2.

Answer (score 4):

The place where your having difficulty is that `.then` doesn't actually block.  It helps you convert synchronous code into asynchronous code, but it doesn't do so for you.  Lets start by considering the synchronous code you are trying to re-write.  Imagine `Db.get` was a synchronous function that returned a value, rather than a promise:

```
var someFn = function (id){
    try {
        var d = Db.get(id, "abc");
        console.log("At 1");
        var d = Db.get(d.id, "def");
        console.log("At 2")
        return d;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("At 3")
    }
};
```

In this case, when I call `someFn` I get a value, not a promise.  That is to say the entire function is synchronous.

If we temporarily fast forward a few years and imagine we could use ES6.  That would let us re-write your function as:

```
var someFn = $q.async(function* (id){
    try {
        var d = yield Db.get(id, "abc");
        console.log("At 1");
        var d = yield Db.get(d.id, "def");
        console.log("At 2")
        return d;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("At 3")
    }
});
```

That looks very similar, but this time we have `Db.get` returning a promise, and `someFn()` will also always return a promise.  The `yield` keyword actually "pauses" the current function until the promise is fulfilled.  This lets it look just like the synchronous code, but it's actually asynchronous.

Rewind to the present, and we need to work out how to write this.  The second argument of a `.then` call is an error handler, so the exact equivalent to the ES6 example would be:

```
var someFn = function (id){
    return Db.get(id, "abc")
        .then(function (d) {
            console.log("At 1");
            return Db.get(d.id, "def");
        })
        .then(function (d) {
            console.log("At 2");
            return d;
        })
        .then(null, function (ex) {
            console.log("At 3")
        });
});
```

Note how each return is only returning from its current function scope.  There's no way to force it to jump all the way out of `someFn`.

Another interesting experiment to do is:

```
Db.get('id', 'abc')
  .then(function () {
    console.log('B');
  });
console.log('A');
```

The above will always log:

```
A
B
```

because `.then` doesn't block.