# Wait for in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a JavaScript function that updates my data.

The user may Click several times and I want to Wait for the Second click while the first click is not finished and so on

```js
  $scope.isLastUpdateFinished = true;

            $scope.onSave = function (isFitToPage) {
                if (!$scope.isLastUpdateFinished)
                    while (!$scope.isLastUpdateFinished) {
                    }

                $scope.isLastUpdateFinished = false;

                    dataService.save($scope.draft, "api/Draft/UpdateDraft/").then(function (data) {
                        if (data.Succeeded && data.Message != null)
                            toaster.pop("warning", _("Dataservice_TTL_Save"), data.Message);
                        if (!data.Succeeded) {
                            modalOptions.headerText = _("Error_InRefreshList");
                            modalOptions.bodyText = data.Message;
                            modalService.showModal(errorDefaults, modalOptions);
                        }


                        if (isFitToPage) {

                            $scope.imageviewer.viewerconfig.controls.imageReload(true, true);
                        }
                        if ($scope.myOtherAside.$scope.$isShown && isFitToPage) {
                            $scope.viewerconfig.controls.imageReload(true, true);
                        }
                        $scope.isLastUpdateFinished = true;
                    });

                    
            };
```

Comment: disable your button till first call is not finished.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307652/promise-api-combining-results-of-2-asynchronous-call

Comment: @singe3 thanks, Why  `if (!$scope.isLastUpdateFinished)
                    while (!$scope.isLastUpdateFinished) {
                    }` don't  work appropriately

Comment: You shuld add breakpoints to debug it, I don't know what your code is doing since this is only a small piece of it.

Comment: checked my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

How about just notifying the user that the app is still working?

```
$scope.isLastUpdateFinished = true;

        $scope.onSave = function (isFitToPage) {
            if (!$scope.isLastUpdateFinished)
                {
```

> ```
>             toaster.pop("info", "Please wait...", "Request already in progress... ");
> ```

```
               return false;
              }

            $scope.isLastUpdateFinished = false;

                dataService.save($scope.draft, "api/Draft/UpdateDraft/").then(function (data) {
                    if (data.Succeeded && data.Message != null)
                        toaster.pop("warning", _("Dataservice_TTL_Save"), data.Message);
                    if (!data.Succeeded) {
                        modalOptions.headerText = _("Error_InRefreshList");
                        modalOptions.bodyText = data.Message;
                        modalService.showModal(errorDefaults, modalOptions);
                    }


                    if (isFitToPage) {

                        $scope.imageviewer.viewerconfig.controls.imageReload(true, true);
                    }
                    if ($scope.myOtherAside.$scope.$isShown && isFitToPage) {
                        $scope.viewerconfig.controls.imageReload(true, true);
                    }
                    $scope.isLastUpdateFinished = true;
                });


        };
```